# Is it OK to pass CoreDispatcher to a Singleton to auto-raise events on UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a Singleton class, LocationManager that handles all the Geo-Location in my Windows Metro app.

Because .PositionChanged events from the Geolocator object are often raised on a background thread, I thought of passing my class a reference to a CoreDispatcher so that it can automatically raise its own events on the UI Thread.  e.g.:

```
public class LocationManager
{
    // Events
    public event EventHandler<LocationUpdatedEventArgs> LocationUpdated = delegate { };

    // Private members
    Geolocator gl = null;
    CoreDispatcher dispatcher = null;

    public void StartUpdating(CoreDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;

        gl = new Geolocator();
        gl.PositionChanged += gl_PositionChanged;
    }

    async void gl_PositionChanged(Geolocator sender, PositionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Ensure this class's event is raised on UI thread
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,  () => 
            {
                LocationUpdated(this,  new LocationUpdatedEventArgs(args.Position));
            }
        );   
    }
```

I wonder if I should be putting the dispatcher.RunAsync stuff in each of my listening UI objects instead (i.e. MainPage.xaml.cs) - but this approach seems to save duplication of code.  Are there any drawbacks to this approach?  For example, could the reference to the dispatcher ever become stale or invalid?

Comment: Have you considered using the observer pattern?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by that, Josh?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)?

What you are describing sounds like a publisher-subsriber relationship. When the publisher has something to publish, all subsribers receive that publication. Your publisher does not have to be singleton, but it can be. Does that help?

Comment: I don't see how this differs from what I'm doing - my LocationManager class raises events, which any other objects (in this case XAML pages) can subscribe to.  In this way, isn't it just the same as what you're describing?  Either way, the essence of my question is really to ascertain the advisability of passing and storing a reference to a CoreDispatcher object.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I avoid placing `Dispatcher` (or similar) objects in any layer above the UI layer. `SynchronizationContext` is better.

In your case, I would take an approach using [Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx) (something very similar can be done using [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)):

```
public class LocationManager
{
  // Events
  public event EventHandler<LocationUpdatedEventArgs> LocationUpdated = delegate { };

  // Private members
  Geolocator gl = null;
  ActionBlock<PositionChangedEventArgs> block = null;

  public void StartUpdating()
  {
    // Set up the block to raise our event on the UI thread.
    block = new ActionBlock<PositionChangedEventArgs>(
        args =>
        {
          LocationUpdated(this, new LocationUpdatedEventArgs(args.Position));
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
          TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(),
        });

    // Start the Geolocator, sending updates to the block.
    gl = new Geolocator();
    gl.PositionChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
      block.Post(args);
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting (and enlightening) approach.  Should CoreDispatcher still be passed in like that for any reason, or can it be taken out of the method arguments?  (i.e. StartUpdating()  )  Out of interest, why do you avoid placing Dispatcher-type objects in any layer above the UI layer?

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize `CoreDispatcher` was still a parameter! I fixed the code (it's not necessary to pass it).

Comment: `Dispatcher` in non-UI layers ties those layers to the specific UI platform. `SynchronizationContext` is a general-purpose "context" that works in any kind of application. So I prefer to use that in my non-UI layers, e.g., a portable library containing business objects, which may be referenced by any type of app: Windows Store, ASP.NET, Console, Windows Forms, etc.